# React Native App crashes intermittently while trying to navigate to another screen. Crash log- Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a screen A and after performing some POST API task, I enable a button to be clicked to be navigated to screen B. That's when the React Native app freezes and crashes, the crash happens randomly. And navigating from other screens to screen B is not a problem, its only screen A from where I am not able to navigate away.

Crash Error - Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x20 in tid 1506 (RenderThread), pid 717 (com.wmecm2)

```
  "dependencies": {

    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^12.1.0",
...
}
```

I tried to find the logs using debug apk on Android studio. Below is the screenshot of the logs
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This fixed the same issue for me:

```
const androidLayerType = Platform.OS === 'android' ? (+sdkLevel >= 31 ? 'hardware' : 'software') : undefined;
...
<WebView ... androidLayerType={androidLayerType}
```